# Odoo Add domain for a field only in create view

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

In my module I have to create a view to set goals for departments. In create form view there is a dropdown (many2one field related to hr.department) with selection widget to select the department. I have 2 requirements:

1. Departments dropdown should be filtered.
2. Filtration should only occur in create view.

I tried with `fields_view_get` and its working fine for the create view. But the problem is filtration occurs in both form view and form update :(

This is my code used in `fields_view_get`:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    result = super(hr_appraisal_goal_department, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu)

    if view_type=='form':
        current_user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
        dept_ids = []
        for groups in current_user.groups_id:
            if groups.name == "Define All Departmental Goals":
                dept_ids= self.pool.get('res.users').search(cr, uid, [])
            elif groups.name == "Define Departmental Goals Only to My Own Department":
                dept_ids.append(current_user.employee_ids.department_id.id)

            #there may be additional conditions in future 

        doc = etree.XML(result['arch'])
        nodes = doc.xpath("//field[@name='department_id']")
        for node in nodes:
            node.set('domain', "[('id', 'in',["+','.join(map(str, dept_ids)) +"])]")
            result['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)

    return result
```

Thanks for a kind help.

Answer (score 0):

What you can take into account is that when you are in "create view", the current record (in this case a `hr_appraisal_goal_department` record) is going to **have no ID**, however, if you are editing it in an "edit view", the record **has already an ID**.

So you can play with this condition when setting the domain.

Comment: Thanks. But how can we check the value of ID in the  fields_view_get method? we have no access to values of current record isn't it?

Comment: You're right, `fields_view_get` brings an empty recordset. I did not try it, so I don't know if the following is going to work, just an idea, but I guess you have to redefine the `many2one` department field, and call a method from the domain attribute in Python code. This method must return a domain, so with an if statement, return one or other depending on if the record has ID or not.

Comment: Exactly! Can we call method  from domain? I couldn't find any way to do that :(  gives error in xml